# Calculate if two moving objects will collide JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, vector, intersection

I have multiple objects, but for the sake of simplicity, 2 objects moving across a JS Canvas each adjusting its own speed/direction/etc.

If they get "near" to eachother, I want to calculate if their paths intersect and then adjust path accordingly so they do not. Or, if the paths intersect but they will cross the intersection point at different times (and wont collide/overlap) then no need to change anything.

I'm using a Javascript Canvas with a (currently) 2D coordinate system with Position and Movement in vector form

```
objects = [];
objects.push(object(...));
objects.push(object(...));

function object() { 
    this.movement = {
        p:{x:0, y:0, z:0},
        v:{x:0, y:0, z:0}
    }

    this.step = function() {
        //various changes to vector V to amend directional vector
        ...
        myvectoradd( this.movement.p, this.movement.v ); 
    }

    this.draw = function() {
        ...
    }

    this.checkCollision = function() {
        //for each object in objects
            //if not self, then
                //if "near" other object
                    //check if path is intersecting with other object
    }


}
```

`objects[0].movement.p` is the Position

`objects[0].movement.v` is the Movement vector (added to position each .step() )

Many thanks,
James

Comment: So how "near" is "near" exactly? And what have you tried in terms of detecting if two points are "near" each other and if their paths intersect. 
Any two non-parallel lines will intersect at some point. If I understand your question correctly you're trying to prevent two points from colliding once they get close enough based on where they'll end up. If you do it that way you may end up needing to use calculus. Why not try something force based?

Comment: Khauri, near() is just a function I have to see if two positional vectors are within a set radius squared (avoiding sqrt() every step as it is quite computationally expensive). For example, in this, I've set 100 pixels/units as the radius. And yes, it's the calculus I'm struggling with ;)

Comment: Are you trying to make something like a node garden? https://nodegarden.js.org/

Comment: No, just trying to make objects move around freely, but avoiding eachother. I've already happily made a flocking/swarming algorithm using rules and forces applied to turn away from nearby objects. This, however, I'm trying to minimise the movements and keep straight as possible. So, two objects moving will become near() and then calculate if their paths intersect. If so, they calculate the i'sect point, the i'sect time, and then decide whether there is any risk of collision. If there is, they both move very slightly to avoid that risk

Comment: Calculus aside, I thought each object near() or in conflict of path could project forward N number of radii circles, and calculate the time AT that circle, and if any of those circles overlap with the other object at the same time, then consider that a collision. Would that seem over the top?